# Scanner in java won't match with my double variable

Tags: java

I have searched for about an hour and have not yet found a solution to my problem.  I am trying to use my scanner variable input to use it later into my switch argument but I currently am stuck on line two on what the correct syntax is in-order for my problem to work correctly.
Here is my java problem:

//Create scanner for KW input

```
    Scanner kw = new Scanner(System.in);
    double kwUsed = kw;

    //Verify if KW is valid
    try
    {
        //KW used data entry
        System.out.println("Please enter KW used: ");
        kwUsed = kw.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("KW entry valid");
    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid entry");
        System.out.println(error);
    }

    //Date entry will be calculated by how much KW user enters
    switch (input)
    {
        case "2/15/13":
            double quarter1 = kwUsed * 0.10;
            break;
        case "4/15/13":
            double quarter2 = kwUsed * 0.12;
            break;
        case "8/15/13":
            double quarter3 = kwUsed * 0.15;
            break;
        case "11/15/13":
            double quarter4 = kwUsed * 0.15;
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid date");

    }
```

Comment: What is the point of this line `double kwUsed = kw;`?

Comment: Just do `double kwUsed;`?

Comment: @Tdorno I am trying to relate kwUsed to my switch but kwUsed is not initiated but if i try to initiate kwUsed my syntax would be double kwUsed = kw.nextDouble(); but I do not want to have an input at line two only in my try/catch to validate it. I do not know the correct syntax to have it correspond with my try/catch and switch.

Comment: @user2926620 See my answer, it provides you with all the proper syntax that you'll need to fix your code.

Comment: @nhgrif I have done double kwUsed but I want it to be a user input so it can be applied to the switch.

Comment: What do you think `kwUsed = kw.nextDouble();` is doing?  Did you actually write this code?  Moreover, you're `switch`ing over a `String` variable you've called `input`, not over your `double` variable called `kwUsed`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wanted to say normally I won't just fix someones code and then paste it, but in this case I feel it's better for the OP to just see some of the small mistakes that were made rather than just ramble on and on.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.BufferedReader;

public class MainTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner kw = new Scanner(System.in);
        double kwUsed = 0;

        // Verify if KW is valid
        try {

            // KW used data entry
            System.out.println("Please enter KW used: ");
            kwUsed = kw.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("KW entry valid");
        } catch (Exception error) {
            System.out.println("Invalid entry");
            System.out.println(error);
        }

        // Date entry will be calculated by how much KW user enters
        String input;
        System.out.println("Enter input case");
        input = kw.next();

        switch (input) {
        case "2/15/13":
            double quarter1 = kwUsed * 0.10;
            break;
        case "4/15/13":
            double quarter2 = kwUsed * 0.12;
            break;
        case "8/15/13":
            double quarter3 = kwUsed * 0.15;
            break;
        case "11/15/13":
            double quarter4 = kwUsed * 0.15;
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid date");

        }
            //handle your quarter1-4 here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks SO much! You cleared things up for me clearly.